# validar formulários em função de select

Tags: html5, validação

Estou trabalhando com **html5** e preciso validar um campo do meu formulário em função de outro.

Tenho um campo `<select>` chamado **Tipo de Documento**, com três opções possíveis (BI,Dire,passaporte) e um outro campo **Numero do Documento**. Preciso que quando uma opção que for selecionada no `<select>` (por exemplo passaporte), o preenchimento do campo **Numero de Documento** aceite apenas caracteres de passaporte e torna-se obrigatório.

Comment: Posta o código do que tu já fez até agora.

Comment: Usa a biblioteca Jquery para fazer essas veirifcações

Comment: Conseguiu resolver amigo?

Answer (score 1):

> Existem muitas formas de se fazer, utilizei jQuery e jQueryMask que é
>   um plugin que formata os inputs conforme a regra que
>   definimos, tbm podia ser feito com regular expression.

```js
$('#divCampo').hide();

  $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#sel').on('change', function(){
   var sel = $('[name="sel"]').val();
   var select = $('#sel :selected').text();
   var esvaziaCampo = $('#campo').val('');
    
  if (sel == '0') {
   $('#divCampo').hide();
  }
  else if (sel == '1') {
   $('#divCampo').show();
   $('#campo').mask('000-000');
   $('#texto').text(select);
  }
  else if (sel == '2') {
   $('#divCampo').show();
   $('#campo').mask('000-000-000');
     $('#texto').text(select);
  }
  else if (sel == '3') {
   $('#divCampo').show();
   $('#campo').mask('(000) 0000-00000');
   $('#texto').text(select);
  }
    
 });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<form action="https://www.google.com">
 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" style="margin-top:25px;">
  <label for="sel">Tipo de documento</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="sel" id="sel">
   <option value="0"></option>
   <option value="1">BI</option>
   <option value="2">Dire</option>
   <option value="3">Passaporte</option>
  </select>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="divCampo" style="margin-top:25px;">
             <label for="campo">Preencha o campo <span id="texto"></span></label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="campo" required><br>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn" value="Enviar">
 </div>
</form>
```